# Add row to dataframe since other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two pandas data frames which have some rows in not common.

Suppose dataframe2 is a subset of dataframe1.

How can I get the rows of dataframe1 which are not in dataframe2?

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame({'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]}) 
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14], 'col3' : [10, 11, 12]})
```

result :

```
df3 = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
       'col2' : [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       'col3' : [10, 11, 12]
 }
```

Comment: df2 is not reproducible,nor is the expected output, please check again

Answer (score 0):

How about using set.union()?

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_union.asp

```py
# convert columns from df1 to a set
set_cols_df1 = set(df1.columns)

# convert columns from df2 to a set
set_cols_df2 = set(df2.columns)

# use set.union()
set_cols_union = set.union(set_cols_df1, set_cols_df2)
```